# Bash help, putting lines of text from various files together into a new file

Tags: bash

Fairly new to bash, I have a few different files, all with thousands of lines each, I want to take each line from each file, and put them together on one line, in a new file,

for example, if file1 contains IPs

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

file2 contains ports

```
123
124
125
126
127
```

file3 contains timestamps, file4 contains a description

i'd like my output to be:

```
192.168.1.1 : 123 : 01/01/2012 : blah blah blah
192.168.1.2 : 124 : 01/02/2012 : blah blah
```

how could i go about putting them all together?

Answer (score 2):

With `paste(1)` and `sed(1)`.

```
paste file1 file2 file3 file4 | sed 's/\t/ : /g' > out
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the four files as four separate file descriptors 3 through 6, then read one line from each in a loop. 0, 1, and 2 are already open as stdin, stdout, and stderr, respectively, so 3 is the first unused descriptor.

```
exec 3< file1
exec 4< file2
exec 5< file3
exec 6< file4

while IFS= read -r ip          <&3 &&
      IFS= read -r port        <&4 &&
      IFS= read -r timestamp   <&5 &&
      IFS= read -r description <&6
do
    echo "$ip : $port : $timestamp : $description"
done
```